# Does Node.js support the String.MatchAll method?

Tags: node.js, regex

When I test the code:

```
let result = 'heymama'.matchAll(/m(a)/g);
```

I get the error "**'heymama'.matchAll is not a function**"

When I run the version:

```
let result = 'heymama'.match(/ma/g);
```

There's no error.

Comment: [`.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) is a recent addition in JS.

Comment: No wonder I had such a tough time locating more info on it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55059473/3832970

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`#String.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#Browser_compatibility) is supported in `Node.js` from version `12.0.0`

Check out the [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#Browser_compatibility) on MDN.

[image]

Comment: Had seen that page but didn't scroll to the compatibility section. Bummer.

Comment: Was having this problem in Docker with 'node:10-alpine', safe to say upgrading to 'node:14-alpine' fixed it!

Answer (score 15):

`matchAll` is available in Node.js starting from v12.0.0

Answer (score 7):

**Before Node 12:**

As @dennis-vash alredy pointed out, it's currently not supported in Node.js.

There is [this](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/match-all) "match-all" npm package alternative though.

```
const matchAll = require("match-all");

let s = "Hello _World_ and _Mars_";
console.log(matchAll(s, /_([a-z]+)_/gi).toArray());
// => [ "World", "Mars" ]
```

Comment: Are there any packages that include types and can be used in Typescript Node projects?

Comment: It is supported in Node v12?  Maybe this answer was from before he updated his answer?